# Distrubution of a sum S over N different operands

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm trying to figure out a way to distribute a sum S over N different operands (b1, b2, .., bn), where b1, b2, ... bn are in a fixed ratio, which is determined by another set of operands (a1,a2, .. an)

Consider a situation where:

Candidate A gets a total of `Ta` votes from N constituencies, with distribution: `{a1, a2, a3 .. aN}`

Candidate B gets a total of `Tb` votes (`Ta` and `Tb` are unrelated, which means `Ta < Tb`, `Ta = Tb` & `Ta > Tb` are all possible) from M constituencies (IMP: M <= N), distribution unknown.

What is the best approach to allot the `Tb` votes to the constituencies b1, b2, b3.. bM such that, they are distributed in the same ratio as a1, a2, a3.. aN.

Some Cases:

1.Ideal

```
Ta = 20 (8,6,4,2) Tb = 10
```

Then we get: Tb (4,3,2,1)

2.Somewhat less ideal

```
Ta = 20(8 ,6, 4, 1 , 1) Tb = 10
```

Then we get (4, 3, 2, 1, 0) which actually means (4,3,2,1) (M < N), and is still tolerable.

Comment: Can you post an example with M<N?

Comment: The second example is actually the case of M < N. I edited the question a little to show it.

Comment: Are you free to choose M? Are you allowed to take an M which is arbitrarily small (although that's unlikely to be a good idea)?

Comment: I suggest you give some examples, keeping a = b, for various M and N. Right now it's not particularly clear what 'distributed in the same ratio' means when M is not equal to N. For example, what does it mean to distribute 10 across, say, 7, or 17, or 77 pots 'in the same ratio' as 4,3,2,1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution:

br = ar * (Tb / Ta)

Which doesn't really work for complex ranges or for a mis-matched Ta and Tb

Like, Ta = 22 (5, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
and Tb = 7

UPDATE: 
I followed following rules to get to the best solution:

1. Keep the ratio as (Tb / Ta) and keep on distributing until you run out.
2. Whenever you round, round up i.e. 3.24 -> 4 and 3.68 also -> 4
3. e.g. Here: b1 = 5 * 7 / 22 => 2, b2 = 5*7/22 = 2, b3 = 4*7/22 = 2, b4 = 1 (Since just one remains)

So we have Tb = 7(2,2,2,1) Which is closest to (5, 5, 4, 2)

Comment: What do you mean by complex ranges?

Answer (score 1):

Is your a_i sorted always? Assuming that's the case, one way to start is to start assigning b_i from the first value of a_i.